# Query with conditions on multiple value column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am building report in Oracle Apex 4.2. Table that report is build on has multiple values inside one of the columns.

```
-----------------------------------
| ID   |  NAME   |  PROJECT_ID    |
-----------------------------------
|  1   |   P1    | 23:45:56       |
|  2   |   P2    |    23          |
|  3   |   P3    |    45:65       |
-----------------------------------
```

I would like to build a query to retrieve names based on project_id's.

```
 Select name from table where project_id = 23;
```

This obviously will return P2 only however I would like to build a query which would return P1 and P2 if we searched for 23.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LIKE instead of = :

```
Select name from table where project_id LIKE '%23%';
```

If you've got a common delimiter such as the ':' in your example you could use the following to exclude results like '123':

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE ':' || project_id || ':' LIKE '%:23:%'
```

By concatenating the delimiter to the front and back of the string, you don't have to write multiple criteria:  LIKE '23:%' OR LIKE '%:23:%' OR LIKE '%:23' to handle the first and last number in the list.

Comment: I am  really sorry but I do not understand why people are up voting this answer. This query would return names for project_ids like : 23,123, 230 ,231 and so on ...

Comment: Based on the sample data it wasn't clear your data had '123' that you were trying to avoid.  Will the 23 always be separated by a ':' ?

Comment: Yes, data ranges between 1 - 50000. Always separated by colon. If there is single instance there is no colon. Before first and after last sign there is no colon.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common design in Apex due to its builtin support for colon-delimited strings (e.g. to drive shuttle controls and other item types).

I generally use this pattern:

```
Select name from table where INSTR(':'||project_id||':',':23:') > 0;
```

P.S. It's a pity about that column name - I would have called it something like `PROJECT_ID_LIST`.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, shuttles can be sometimes real pain. With regards to column naming convention I agree with you that it should be named differently but that is only example...